# Convert dictionary entry of xarray.Dataset to numpy array (for xy coord contour plotting)

Tags: python, dataset, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to plot, a dictionary entry, which contains lat,on coordinates on a xy coordinate ( lat-lon). The variable looks like:

```
 <class 'method'>
 <bound method Mapping.values of <xarray.Dataset>
 Dimensions:  (lat: 96, lon: 144)
 Coordinates:
 lev_p    int32 200
 Dimensions without coordinates: lat, on
 Data variables:
 V        (lat, lon) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(96, 144), meta=np.ndarray>>
```

I want to plot V, as contour against lat and lon but when I try to plot it I get the following error:

`TypeError: cannot directly convert an xarray.Dataset into a numpy array. Instead, create an xarray.DataArray first, either with indexing on the Dataset or by invoking the` to_array() `method.`

I tried to convert the dictionary values to an array with .to_array as well as using map(float,variable) but none worked.
I can't figure out what is going on. Any advice or help with this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was actually an easy one - it was enough to extract the dictionary value and then our of that extract the variable so instead of doing something like ds['Experiment'] and get the xarray.Dataset I would do ds['Experiment']['V'] so I would get the dictionary and out of it the particular V value.